# Passing 2D arrays to a function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to pass two 2D arrays (both the same size; 8 by 4) to a function and set one equal to the other (with some elements in a different order but that doesnt really matter).  So far I have:

```
int main() {
    double** Array1;
    double** Array1;

    // MALLOC BOTH OF THEM
    ....

    // PUT STUFF IN ARRAY1
    ....

    CopyFunction(&Array1, &Array2);
}

void CopyFunction(double*** Array1, double*** Array2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        *Array2[i][0] = *Array1[i][0];
        *Array2[i][1] = *Array1[i][1];
        *Array2[i][2] = *Array1[i][2];
        *Array2[i][3] = *Array1[i][3];
    }
}
```

But I am getting segfault errors like this:

```
 *** Break *** segmentation violation


===========================================================
There was a crash.
This is the entire stack trace of all threads:
===========================================================
```

Comment: There's no reason to use `malloc` in C++. Use `new` instead. That said, there's very little reason to use `new` in C++. Use RAII instead. If these were vectors, your code would be as simple as `Array2 = Array1;`. Relevant: http://klmr.me/slides/modern-cpp/#1

Comment: I completely agree @chris but I'm using a package someone else has made which needs a vector of 2d arrays so I have to stick with this! Thanks

Comment: Irrelavant: since you are not modifying the pointers in copyFunction, why don't you just pass the pointer `double**` instead of `double***`?

Comment: Hmm True.  I think my original intention was to perform the shuffling of 1D arrays within the 2D arrays using some clever pointer rearrangment rather than just copying them like above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want:

```
    (*Array2)[i][0] = (*Array1)[i][0];
    (*Array2)[i][1] = (*Array1)[i][1];
    (*Array2)[i][2] = (*Array1)[i][2];
    (*Array2)[i][3] = (*Array1)[i][3];
```

As it's written, you're not dereferencing the arrays in the right order, due to order of operations. The dereferences done by `[i][N]` are happening before `*`. The original version is the same as doing `*(*(*(Array1 + i) + N))` (due to how `[]` really works), but what you want is something like `*(*(*Array1 + i) + N)`, which is why you have to add parentheses like I did.

Even better, though, would be this:

```
void CopyFunction(double** Array1, double** Array2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        Array2[i][0] = Array1[i][0];
        Array2[i][1] = Array1[i][1];
        Array2[i][2] = Array1[i][2];
        Array2[i][3] = Array1[i][3];
    }
}
```

And even better than that would be this:

```
std::copy_n(*Array1, 32, *Array2);
```

Edit: though `std::copy_n` doesn't really work for you if you're changing the order of some of the elements when you do the copy.

Comment: Cheer @Cornstalks but I'm not exactly copying them I'm mixing the order.  Good to know about std::copy_n though!

Comment: @JackMedley: Ah, ok, well the code in your question is a simple copy.

Comment: Yeah it got a brief mention in the preamble but I figured it wasnt the switching that was messing up - its always pointers!

Comment: @JackMedley: And of course, I missed that little mention in the preamble :)

Answer (score 3):

You should be doing

```
(*Array2)[i][0] = (*Array1)[i][0];
```

instead of

```
*Array2[i][0] = *Array1[i][0];
```

As index operator has higher precedence

Answer (score 2):

Array subscript has a higher precedence than `*` operator, so you need to include parentheses in order to first dereference `Array2` pointer to get a 2D array:

```
    (*Array2)[i][0] = (*Array1)[i][0];
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 1):

```
int main() {
double** Array1;
double** Array1;

// MALLOC BOTH OF THEM
....

// PUT STUFF IN ARRAY1
....

CopyFunction(Array1, Array2);
```

}

```
void CopyFunction(double** Array1, double** Array2) {
   for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    Array2[i][0] = Array1[i][0];
    Array2[i][1] = Array1[i][1];
    Array2[i][2] = Array1[i][2];
    Array2[i][3] = Array1[i][3];
}
```

}

You should probably consider passing in the array sizes as a parameter.